# How to package AWS CDK into Lambda layer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

What is the best way to bundle up the AWS CDK as a Lambda layer please?

I need to call the CDK from a Java process, so wish to use the Java 11 runtime and then install Nodejs and the CDK as 2 separate layers.  Currently I download the Nodejs binaries and then use something like the following:

```
    LayerVersion nodeLayer = LayerVersion.Builder.create(this, "node-layer")
            .description("Layer containing Node.js")
            .code(
                    Code.fromAsset(somePathToNodejs)
            )
            .build();
```

then refer to the layer within the Lambda constructor / builder.

The CDK is installed as `npm install -g aws-cdk`, so I don't know how best to bundle this up in a similar fashion.

Comment: So you want to run npm install on a specific folder and upload the content as a layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using a Docker container to install the `aws-cdk` module into a specific path, then zip up the container and copying it to a bind-mounted directory so that it is available on the underlying host.

I built the project using Gradle and the [`gradle-docker-plugin`](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin) by Ben Muschko. I have not spent time trying to use a smaller Node image to speed up builds.

```
task createCdkDockerfile(type: Dockerfile) {
    from 'node:latest'
    defaultCommand('/bin/bash', '-c', "apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip && mkdir -p /nodejs && npm config set prefix /nodejs/bin && npm install -g aws-cdk && pushd /nodejs/bin && zip -r --symlinks /opt/aws-cdk.zip *")
}

task buildCdkImage(type:DockerBuildImage) {
    dependsOn createCdkDockerfile
    images.add('my-aws-cdk:latest')
}

ext.maybeConvertWindowsPath = { path ->
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        path = "/${path.replace("\\", "/").replace(":", "")}"
    }
    return path
}

task createCdkContainer(type: DockerCreateContainer) {
    def dockerBindDir = new File(buildDir, "docker")
    dockerBindDir.mkdirs()
    dependsOn buildCdkImage
    targetImageId buildCdkImage.getImageId()
    hostConfig.autoRemove = true
    hostConfig.binds = ["${maybeConvertWindowsPath(buildDir.toString())}/docker" : "/opt"]
}

task startCdkContainer(type: DockerStartContainer) {
    dependsOn createCdkContainer
    targetContainerId createCdkContainer.getContainerId()
}

task waitCdkContainer(type: DockerWaitContainer) {
    dependsOn startCdkContainer
    targetContainerId createCdkContainer.getContainerId()
}
```

The zip file is available at `${buildDir}/docker/aws-cdk.zip`.

Adding the CDK as a layer is as per the Nodejs example in my question, so something like this:

```
LayerVersion nodeLayer = LayerVersion.Builder.create(this, "aws-cdk-layer")
        .description("Layer containing AWS CDK")
        .code(
                Code.fromAsset(somePathTo-aws-cdk.zip)
        )
        .build();
```

Points to watch out for:

- if building on Windows, zipping up on Windows then unzipping on Linux will give issues with files that should be executable no longer being executable, i.e. `cdk` itself.
- bind mounting directories seems to have issues when on Windows, hence the need to sanitize the filename.
- when zipping, it's important to use the `--symlinks` option, otherwise the `cdk` executable will not be able to find the `cdk.js` file.

I would have preferred using `tar` to zip the file up, but `fromAsset()` won't accept tar files.

Comment: Nice answer.  I've got a similar solution on SO that goes in a slightly more Dockerized approach.  I build my artifacts in a `Code.fromDockerBuild` instead of `Code.fromAsset`.  So you build an identical artifact, regardless of whoever's laptop or even in the CodePipeline.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69081396/2597237