# How do I include a custom Lambda Layer into a pipeline stack? (AWS-CDK)

Tags: aws-cdk

I have two stacks,

- Application stack
- Pipeline stack

What is the official way of including a custom lambda layer into the pipeline stack so that it relays code location information back to my application stack?

I have followed the documentation to make regular lambdas work... found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/codepipeline_example.html?shortFooter=true

Some documentation and/or example code would be greatly helpful.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Sucks that no one has answered this question until now but I was trying to solve the same problem and came up with this, so I hope it helps someone like us :)

There are zillions of ways to skin this cat but I am trying to go for clean CICD with easy developer work.  The route I chose was to build my Lambda Layer with a `Code.from_docker_build()` object.  I supplied a `Dockerfile` I wrote, which can package my code into whatever code artifact I need and then CDK knows how to handle it.  That becomes my Lambda Layer, which I can then consume in other stacks/lambdas.

So here's what you need to do:

1. Create a `Dockerfile` in your repo which can build your code into an artifact.

   1. This `Dockerfile` should finish by putting your single code artifact file into the `/asset` directory.  You should only have a tar ball or a zip or whatever, just 1 file that is your code in "artifact" form that can run in lambda
2. use `Code.from_docker_build()` as your code object in your function.

   ```
   class YourLambdaLayer(cdk.Stack):
       def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
          super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
          # Create Lambda Layer
          new_version = LayerVersion(self, construct_id,
              layer_version_name=construct_id,
              code=Code.from_docker_build(
                  path=os.path.abspath("./"),              
                  file='Dockerfile'
              ),
              compatible_runtimes=[Runtime.PYTHON_3_8],
          )
          # Create an export to use from other stacks
          cdk.CfnOutput(self, f"{construct_id}-Arn-Export",
              value=new_version.layer_version_arn,
              export_name='your-cool-layer-Arn'
          )
   ```

Everything else from the example in the link you posted *should* work as you expect it.  The only difference is that you're using a docker image to bundle your artifacts instead of supplying a zip or something like that.

This is what a pipeline resource would look like for a Python function, built using a Dockerfile in the pipeline...

```
class YourCICDStack(cdk.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope, id, env=None,... **kwargs):

        super().__init__(scope, id,..., env=env, **kwargs)

        code_repo = Repository(self, 'a-git-repo-in-code-commit',
            repository_name='a-cool-python-package-from-u',
            description='you can be long winded whilst describing, if you like :)'
        )

        pipeline = CodePipeline(self, 'resource-name-goes-here',
            pipeline_name='pipeline-name-goes-here',
            docker_enabled_for_synth=True, # !!! important !!!
            synth=ShellStep("Synth",
                input=CodePipelineSource.code_commit(
                    repository=code_repo,
                    branch='development',
                ),
                commands=[
                    "pip install -r requirements.txt",
                    "npm install -g aws-cdk",
                    f"cdk synth ..."
                ]
            )
        )
        # Add the stages for deploying
        your_stage = pipeline.add_stage(YourLayerStage(self, ..., env=env))
        your_stage.add_post(ManualApprovalStep('approval'))
```

So now that you've got your pipeline publishing your Lambda Layer, you would use it from other stacks using either the [from_layer_version_arn()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/LayerVersion.html#aws_cdk.aws_lambda.LayerVersion.from_layer_version_attributes) or [from_layer_version_attributes()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/LayerVersion.html#aws_cdk.aws_lambda.LayerVersion.from_layer_version_attributes).

Those are both class functions, so you use them in your other stacks by doing something like

```
my_cool_layer_ref = LayerVersion.from_layer_version_arn(
    cdk.Fn.import_value('your-cool-layer-Arn')
)
# Include it in your other stacks/functions
some_other_func = Function(...,
    layers=[my_cool_layer_ref],
    ...
)
```